# java printf cannot print char array

Tags: java

I am looking for a help to my code in java as I wanted to print only the uppercase of ASCII. So I made an array and run a for loop. I made an if condition to access the characters from 65 to 90, then I used this format to print the value system.

```
out.printf("%c : ",ch[x]).
```

Unfortunately I got garbage as output.
here is the complete code:

```
           for(int x=0; x<ch.length; x++) {
            if(ch[x]>=65||ch[x]<=90) {
               System.out.printf("%c ",ch[x]);
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code

Comment: Tag the question with `java`, research string + java + toupper, post your code to help us fix yours.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: executed on jshell, got proper output for input: char[] ch = {'A','B','C','D','a','b'}; output: A B C D a b

Comment: when i use && instead || i got nothing printed

Comment: @Baba, char[] ch = {'A','B','C','D','a','b'}; for(int x=0; x<ch.length; x++) { if(ch[x]>=65&&ch[x]<=90){System.out.printf("%c ",ch[x]);}}
output: A B C D

Answer (score 1):

As @YCF_L said, use `&&`, and may, I recommend the forEach :

```
char[] ch = new char[]{'A', 'z', 'S', 'Z', 'H', '1', 'o'};
for (char c : ch) {

    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) {
        System.out.printf("%c ", c);
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
A S Z H
```

---

[ideone demo](https://www.ideone.com/Np10IA)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use isUpperCase() method:

```
for(int x=0; x<ch.length; x++) {
        if(isUpperCase(ch[x])) {
           System.out.printf("%c ",ch[x]);
        }
      }
```

If you don't want to use the method:

```
for(int x=0; x<ch.length; x++) {
        if(ch[x]>=65 && ch[x]<=90) {
           System.out.printf("%c ",ch[x]);
        }
      }
```